# Using mechanize with watir + phantomjs

Tags: ruby, macos, phantomjs, mechanize, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to insert the html generated from phantom js into a mechanize object so that I can easily search it. I've tried the following to no avail...

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
url = "www.google.com"
b.goto url

agent = Mechanize.new
#Following is not executed at same time...
#Error 1: lots of errors
page = agent.get(b.html)

#Error 2: `parse': wrong number of arguments (1 for 3) (ArgumentError)
page = agent.parse(b.html)

#Error 3 last ditch effort: undefined method `agent' 
page = agent(b.html)
```

As I think it through I'm beginning to wonder if I can mechanize an existing html object... I initially got onto it via: http://shane.in/2014/01/headless-web-scraping/ & http://watirmelon.com/2013/02/05/watir-webdriver-with-ghostdriver-on-osx-headless-browser-testing/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would using Mechanize be easier to search with than using Watir?

Comment: mainly to make it easier to search for specific nth level children within the css, however I do see that I can use xpath within watir

Comment: You can also use CSS selectors in Watir. However, there are often more Watir-like ways.

Comment: You don't need Mechanize for that, just Nokogiri. Good reasons to use Mechanize would be forms or cookies. And yes, searching the html with Nokogiri is often better than using Watir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in the same situation. I write a lot of code with Mechanize so that I do not want to move to `nokogiri` when using `watir`. Below code is how I did.

```
require 'watir'
require 'mechanize'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto(url)
html = b.html
a = Mechanize.new
page = Mechanize::Page.new(nil, {'content-type'=>'text/html'}, html, nil, a)
```

You could use page to search for elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'watir'
require 'nokogiri'

b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
url = "http://google.com"
b.goto url

p Nokogiri::HTML(b.html)
```

You are probably better off just using Nokogiri for this [that is, if you only need to search for some data in source].

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I have solution below for someone who want to stick with `mechanize`